# Joining and merging two dataframes with no multiplicity

Tags: r, join, merge

The title is really confusing I know, but I have to explain my problem.
I have 2 datasets where first contains frequency of citations by years for every article which is represented by pmid. It look like this:

```
       pmid year freq
1  14561399 2011    1
2  14561399 2012    3
3  18511332 2010    1
4  21193046 2012    2
5  21193046 2013    2
6  14561399 2013    1
7  18511332 2011    1
8  18511332 2012    3
9  14561399 2014    1
10 16533158 2013    2
```

and the second contains article features and looks like this:

```
      pmid title_char title_wrds
1 20711763         75          9
2 20734175        109         12
3 20058113         93         13
4 20625865        142         17
5 20517661        103         12
6 20195930        128         16
```

Both dataset as you can see contains "pmid", which is parameter by which I need to "merge" or "join" this dataset. That's not a problem, it could be done with just merge() function or with dplyr package. But when I do this, results look like this:

```
   pmid title_char title_wrds year freq
1   184         77         10 2010    1
2   406        142         20 2008    1
3   407        110         16 2008    1
4   407        110         16 2003    1
5   408         79         10 1998    1
6   450         58          7 2012    2
7   450         58          7 2009    1
```

My problem is - as you can see for example lines 2 and 3 - these two lines contains the same article (the same pmid, same features) but it is in the two line because of the year of citation.

```
    pmid title_char title_wrds year freq
 3   407        110         16 2008    1
 4   407        110         16 2003    1
```

And I want something like this:

```
    pmid title_char title_wrds year2008Freq year2003Freq
 1   407        110         16            1            1
```

That is 1 line per 1 article.

Comment: Does `reshape(dfN, idvar=c('pmid', 'title_char', 'title_wrds'), timevar='year', direction='wide')` helps? or use `library(reshape2); dcast(dfN, ...~year, value.var='freq')`

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
library(reshape2)
res <- dcast(dfN, ...~paste0('year', year, 'Freq'), value.var='freq')
```

#### data

```
dfN <- structure(list(pmid = c(184L, 406L, 407L, 407L, 408L, 450L, 450L
 ), title_char = c(77L, 142L, 110L, 110L, 79L, 58L, 58L),
 title_wrds = c(10L, 
 20L, 16L, 16L, 10L, 7L, 7L), year = c(2010L, 2008L, 2008L, 2003L, 
 1998L, 2012L, 2009L), freq = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L)),
 .Names = c("pmid", 
 "title_char", "title_wrds", "year", "freq"), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"))
```